# How to set systemd runlevel without systemctl?

Tags: systemd, configuration

How to set systemd runlevel without systemctl?

I have access to Raspbery Pi image content, so I can edit any file there, but I can't run neither `systemctl`, nor `raspi-config`. How to change runlevel by editing config files?

Comment: There is no runlevel in systemd. There may be a `runlevel` command that tries to map a system V runlevel to the best possible equivalent in systemd.

Comment: The default target is a symlink `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` to the appropriate unit file, e.g. `/usr/lib/systemd/system/graphical.target`. You can override it with a kernel parameter `systemd.unit=multi-user.target`.

Comment: Is your inability to run them due to a lack of root access?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is change the symlink of `default.target`.

For the Debian-based Raspberry PiOS, you can find it at

```
/etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

It will point to a target in `/lib/systemd/system`. There you will also find symlinks for each runlevel correspondence, check them and see to where your `default.target` should point.

```
$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/runlevel?.target | cut -c 40-
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel0.target -> poweroff.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel1.target -> rescue.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel2.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel3.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel4.target -> multi-user.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel5.target -> graphical.target
/lib/systemd/system/runlevel6.target -> reboot.target
```

So for e.g. runlevel3 make sure that `/etc/systemd/system/default.target` is a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target`. This will then apply once you boot from the image.